# cannot use background position to position div

Tags: html, css

I would like to display a circle on top of a map. But the circle is always displayed on the left top of the map regardless of the background position coordinates. I tried to set the background position as 40px 40px but the circle still displayed on the left top of the map. Can someone tell me how I could display the circle anywhere on top of the map by specifying the coordinates?

Here are my code snippets:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="theIcon" style="position: absolute;z-index:100;width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 50%;font-size: 10px;color: #fff;line-height: 30px;text-align: center;background: red;background-position: 40px 40px";></div>

    <div class="ClsdrawArea" id="draw_area" style="width: 900px; height:900px; background-image: url('https://s30.postimg.org/snqug5qd9/Path_Finding_Map.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:cover">
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: maybe if you post some CSS since this is a question related to CSS...

Comment: The css is there. I am using inline css.

Comment: inline css is not a best practice and doesn't help readibility of your code. Better use a separate stylesheet or at least style definition on the head section

Comment: What do you mean from the map? Try to make a full width and full height (as the map's height and width) div over the map, as a child with a transparent background and now you can use CSS background position to put the circle where you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For make this use `top:40px` and `left:40px`. You can use too `position:fixed` for fix the circle on top

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="theIcon" style="position: absolute;z-index:100;width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 50%;font-size: 10px;color: #fff;line-height: 30px;text-align: center;background: red;background-position: 40px 40px;top:40px;left:40px";></div>

    <div class="ClsdrawArea" id="draw_area" style="width: 900px; height:900px; background-image: url('https://s30.postimg.org/snqug5qd9/Path_Finding_Map.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:cover">
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

position absolute his relative to your web page. Try with

```
position : relative;
top : 50px; 
left : 50px;
```

Comment: Always an answer works better with a demo, you can easily add a demo for your answer then the user can test it to see if this is what that will answer his needs

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `top` & `left` properties to the positioned element (the red dot), and in addition, add to its wrapper element `position:relative;` so it will act as the positioning context, instead of the `body`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div id="theIcon" style="position: absolute;z-index:100;width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 50%;font-size: 10px;color: #fff;line-height: 30px;text-align: center;background: red;top:120px;left:234px;"></div>

    <div class="ClsdrawArea" id="draw_area" style="width: 900px; height:900px; background-image: url('https://s30.postimg.org/snqug5qd9/Path_Finding_Map.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:cover">
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to provide position where you wanted it to render by providing combination of top/left/bottom/right and their pixel values.

I just added top and left style in your code snippet and you can see that it is showing shifted to right to top left corner.

Its coz when you specify position absolute it takes it position as top left corner of its parent dom element (having relative position.)

below is your code with my added style of top and left

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="theIcon" style="position: absolute;z-index:100;width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 50%;font-size: 10px;color: #fff;line-height: 30px;text-align: center;background: red;background-position: 40px 40px;left:100px; top:20px";></div>

    <div class="ClsdrawArea" id="draw_area" style="width: 900px; height:900px; background-image: url('https://s30.postimg.org/snqug5qd9/Path_Finding_Map.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:cover">
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use coordinates you would need to use Map and Area tags in HTML

To just position the circle in a specific place use

```
TOP:50px; 
LEFT:50px;
```

Comment: I guess you forgot the "position" and also it's better CSS styles being in lower case

Comment: He had already declared position so didn't include it but you are correct about the lowercase my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

background-position is for sets the starting position of a background image (background-image)

its not work for background colors.

you can do it with left and top properties with position:absolute or relative like this:

```
  <div id="theIcon" style="position: absolute;z-index:100;width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 50%;font-size: 10px;color: #fff;line-height: 30px;text-align: center;background: red;left: 40px;top: 40px;"></div>
```